# How to make Dynamic Pivot Column-row value conditional

Tags: sql

I have a couple of tables for instance

```
dbo.ServiceEntry(ID,SystemID)
dbo.ServiceEntryPart(ID,PartID,ServiceEntryID,RevisionNumber)
dbo.Part(ID,Description,..,..,InstrumentTypeID,PlatformID,BaseLineNumber)
dbo.Sytem(ID,FullName,PlatformID)
dbo.SystemModule(ID,SystemID,InstrumentTypeID)
dbo.InstrumentType(ID,Name)
```

I wrote a dynamic pivot query which returns parts which were used in service entries and had a revision number.  So basically service entry is created on a system and part(s) were selected in that service entry and the user added a revision number for the selected part(s)

So results look like as follows

```
PartID  PartDescription  System1  System2  System3
1020    xyz              NULL      102      NULL
```

Now I need to add conditions in the query that if there are no matching service entries for a part then I will replace the pivot column-row value with the Part Baseline Number from the part table instead of the revision number from service entry part table

so essentially from the above if part 1020 was not used in a service entry then the result will look as follows where the sytem column row value is the part baseline number from part table. System 3 value will not be populated with the baseline revision number because that part does not belong to that system.

```
PartID  PartDescription    System1  System2  System3
    1020    xyz               100      100      NULL
```

So how could I add the above condition in my existing dynamic pivot query?

```
    DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =  
           COALESCE(
             @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' +  cast(SystemFullName as Nvarchar) + ']',
             '[' + cast(SystemFullName as varchar)+ ']'
           )
        FROM System

    DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
       SELECT *
       FROM (

        select p.HighLevelPart as Subsystem,
        p.ID as PartNumber,p.PartDescription as Description,
         s.SystemFullName,
          sep.PartRevisionNumber AS Revision from ServiceEntry se
        inner join ServiceEntryPart sep
        on sep.ServiceEntryID = se.ID
        inner join Part p on
        sep.PartID = p.ID
        inner join System s on
        se.SystemID = s.ID
        and p.HighLevelPart is not null
        and sep.PartRevisionNumber is not null
) AS PivotData
   PIVOT (
     MAX(Revision)
     FOR SystemFullName IN (
       ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
     ) 
   ) AS PivotTable   
' 
exec sp_executesql @PivotTableSQL
```

Comment: did coalesce work for u?

Comment: @RADAR nope that did not work. I revised my question and added detailed information about the problem